# What causes the strange behaviors when calling a lambda with [&] capture clause inside which a variable outside current scope is used in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, compilation

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<void ()> f()
{
    int x = 666;
    return [&] { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
}

int main()
{
    f()();
    return 0;
}
```

### Compiling with GCC 7.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic (WSL):

#### No optimization

```
$ g++ -o main -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp
$ ./main
666
```

#### `-O1`

```
$ g++ -o main -O1 -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp
$ ./main
0
```

#### `-O2`

```
$ g++ -o main -O2 -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:31: warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     return [&] { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
                               ^
$ ./main
32699
```

#### `-O3`

```
$ g++ -o main -O3 -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:31: warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     return [&] { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
                               ^
$ ./main
32528
```

### Compiling with TDM-GCC 9.2.0 on Windows 10 x64:

#### No optimization

```
>g++ -o main.exe -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp

>.\main.exe
666
```

#### `-O1`

```
>g++ -o main.exe -O1 -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp

>.\main.exe
0
```

#### `-O2`

```
>g++ -o main.exe -O2 -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp

>.\main.exe
0
```

#### `-O3`

```
>g++ -o main.exe -O3 -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp

>.\main.exe
0
```

### Compiling with MSVC 19.27.29111 on Windows 10 x64:

#### No optimization

```
>cl /EHsc main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29111 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29111.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj

>.\main.exe
8402693
```

#### `/O1`

```
>cl /EHsc /O1 main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29111 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29111.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj

>.\main.exe
666
```

#### `/O2`

```
>cl /EHsc /O2 main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29111 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29111.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj

>.\main.exe
666
```

As you can see, with different compilers and optimization levels, the program outputs `666`, `0`, or a garbage value. Why does the above happen?

Comment: It seems you put a lot of effort into this. Sadly, this is simply [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979248/why-does-this-simple-program-result-in-puppies-puppies-puppies-to-the-console) meaning that anything and everything can happen.

Comment: 6 upvotes for a zero-research post about UB. Something is not right with this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You capture `x` by reference in the lambda and after leaving `f()` it becomes a dangling reference as `x` gets destroyed. You have a classic UB. To avoid it you can capture `x` by value by writing `[x]` or `[=]` instead of `[&]`.